# Prove that $X$ is not homotopic to any graph if its covering space is homotopic to a product space

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, covering-spaces

Let $p: \widetilde{X} \to X$ be a covering map. Assume that $\widetilde{X}$ is path connected, and that $X$ is path connected and locally path connected. Assume that $\widetilde{X}$ is homotopy equivalent to a space of the form $Y\times Z$, for neither $Y$ nor $Z$ simply connected. Prove that $X$ is not homotopy equivalent to any graph.
$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}$
$\newcommand{\mathbbm}{\textbf}$

Proof: We proceed by way of contradiction, and suppose $X \simeq \Gamma$ for some graph $\Gamma$. Then $\pi_1 (X)\cong F_n$ for some free group of rank $n$. Next, since $p$ is a covering map, then the induced homomorphism $p_\ast : \pi_1 (\widetilde{X})\to \pi_1 (X,x)$ is injective. Therefore $\pi_1 (\widetilde{X})$ will correspond to some subgroup $H \leq F_n$. Every subgroup of a free group is free, so let $H=F_m$.

By assumption, we have that $\widetilde{X} \simeq Y\times Z$ for some non-simply-connected spaces $Y$ and $Z$, which induces $\pi_1 (\widetilde{X}) \cong \pi_1 (Y\times Z)$. Since $\widetilde{X}$ is path-connected, then $Y\times Z$ is also path-connected by invariance under homotopy. A product space is path-connected only if the component spaces are path-connected, so $Y$ and $Z$ are path-connected. This being the case, we will have $\pi_1 (Y\times Z) \cong \pi_1 (Y)\times \pi_1 (Z)$. Combining we then get $\pi_1(\widetilde{X})\cong \pi_1 (Y)\times \pi_1 (Z) \cong F_m$, which we will now proceed to show is impossible.

Let $P = \pi_1 (Y,y)\times \pi_1 (Z,z)$ for some base points $y$ and $z$, and identify the component spaces as subgroups of $P$ as follows,
\begin{align*}
\pi_1 (Y,y)' &:= \{([\alpha],1_Z)\in P: [\alpha] \in \pi_1 (Y,y) \} \cong \pi_1(Y,y)\\
\pi_1 (Z,z)' &:= \{(1_Y,[\beta])\in P: [\beta] \in \pi_1 (Z,z) \} \cong \pi_1(Z,z), \\
\end{align*}
where $1_Y$ and $1_Z$ denote the constant loop, and $[\alpha]$ and $[\beta]$ denote homotopy classes of nontrivial loops at $y$ and $z$ respectively. Since $Y$ and $Z$ are non-simply-connected, their fundamental groups each contain at least one nontrivial element. Under the above identification, all elements of $\pi_1(Y,y)$ and $\pi_1 (Z,z)$ will commute with each other (and, by extension, so will elements in $P$).

Since all nontrivial elements of $F_m$ which commute with each other are powers of a common element, if $P\cong F_m$ then all elements of $P$ must be powers of a common element. That element is either of the form $([\alpha],1_Z),(1_Y,[\beta]),$ or $([\alpha],[\beta])$ for nontrivial $[\alpha]$ and $[\beta]$.

Consider the first two cases and observe that since isomorphism preserves the order of elements and every nontrivial element of $F_m$ has infinite order, therefore $([\alpha],1_Z)$ and $(1_Y,[\beta])$ (identified with $[\alpha]$ and $[\beta]$, respectively) will have infinite order. Hence there cannot exist $\omega\in \Z$ such that $([\alpha],1_Z)^\omega = (1_Y,[\beta])$ or $(1_Y,[\beta])^\omega = ([\alpha], 1_Z)$. Moreover, if $[\alpha]$ and $[\beta]$ have infinite order, then clearly $([\alpha],[\beta])$ will also have infinite order, so there cannot exist $\eta\in \Z$ such that $([\alpha],[\beta])^\eta = ([\alpha],1_Z)$ or $([\alpha],[\beta])^\eta = (1_Y,[\beta])$.

Consequently, for any element $([\alpha],[\beta])\in P$ ($[\alpha]$ and $[\beta]$ not necessarily nontrivial), there will exist some $([\gamma],[\delta])\in P$ such that $([\gamma],[\delta])$ is not a power of $([\alpha],[\beta])$, which contradicts the properties of a free group, so $P\ncong F_m$.

Due to the isomorphism induced by homotopy equivalence, $\pi_1 (\widetilde{X})\ncong F_m$, so $\pi_1 (\widetilde{X}) \nleq F_n$ which would imply that $\widetilde{X}$ is not a covering space. By assumption, $\widetilde{X}$ is in fact a covering of $X$, so it must be that $\pi_1 (X)\ncong F_n$ and therefore $X \not\simeq \Gamma$. $\Box$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: You could simplify your proof greatly if, after using topology to determine that $\pi_1(X) \times \pi_1(Y) \approx F_m$, you then worked out a strictly algebraic proof that a free group is not isomorphic to a product of two nontrivial groups.

Comment: @LeeMosher is this not what I have done with my order of elements/commutativity argument in the second half?

Comment: oh, i see what you mean now. if i just prove that is true for any arbitrary nontrivial groups, i don't even need to mess around with $\pi_1$ of the various stuff.